# Printing ONLY(not the entire frame) a label in java swings

Tags: java, swing, printing, jframe, actionlistener

Check the image below

[image]

the barcode is added as a label.Once I click on Print I need to print only the barcode.How am I suppose to it.I saw few examples but in that they printed the whole frame,i.e including the print button on the frame.

**UPDATE**
Now I am getting the print to the top left corner.How to position it wherever I want it

[image]

Comment: Where is the barcode image? You can take a simple way by printing the barcode image not the label.

Comment: it is stored in my drive,i retrieve it to show the user and then ask to print it as shown in the image

Comment: Ok, you can simply do this code: `Desktop.getDesktop().print(new File(path/to/image));`  using [**Dekstop**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html) class, also it needs a `try-catch` block don't forget that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What needs to be done is simply to implement `Printable` for a single `Component`.

Here is a basic implementation example that could shed some light on the subject:

```
/**
 * Allows for printing a single UI component.
 * @author Ben Barkay
 */
public class ComponentPrinter implements Printable {
    /**
     * The component to be printed.
     */
    Component component;

    /**
     * The amount of pixels to shift the component to the right.
     */
    int translateX;

    /**
     * The amount of pixels to shift the component to the bottom.
     */
    int translateY;

    /**
     * Constructs a new <code>ComponentPrinter</code> for the specified component.
     * @param component     The component that this component printer will print.
     * @param translateX    The amount of pixels to move the component towards the right.
     * @param translateY    The amount of pixels to move the component towards the bottom.
     */
    public ComponentPrinter(Component component, int translateX, int translateY) {
        this.component = component;
        this.translateX = translateX;
        this.translateY = translateY;
    }

    /**
     * Prints the component of this <code>ComponentPrinter</code>.
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public int print(Graphics graphics, PageFormat format, int pageIndex)
            throws PrinterException {
        // We assume that there is only one page.
        if (pageIndex == 0) {
            // Position the component appropriately
            ((Graphics2D)graphics).translate(translateX, translateY);

            // Paints the component on the graphics that are about to be printed for this page.
            component.paint(graphics);
            return PAGE_EXISTS;
        }

        // We don't have a page other than the first page.
        return NO_SUCH_PAGE;
    }
}
```

Usage of it would be like so:

```
JLabel yourJLabelHere = null;
int moveToTheRight = 100;
int moveToTheBottom = 50;
PrinterJob printJob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
printJob.setPrintable(new ComponentPrinter(yourJLabelHere, moveToTheRight, moveToTheBottom));
if (printJob.printDialog()) {
    try { 
        printJob.print();
    } catch(PrinterException pe) {
        System.out.println("Error printing: " + pe);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks it worked.But I got the print right at the top left corner.How to position to center or anywhere on the screen.Putting the image in the update

Comment: @user2958963 In `ComponentPrinter#print(Graphics, PageFormat, int)`, you could cast `Graphics` to `Graphics2D` and use `Graphics2D#translate(int, int)` to move it around. Right before `compnent.paint(graphics);`, issue `((Graphics2D)graphics).translate(addToX, addToY);` where `addToX` is the amount of pixels to move to the right and `addToY` is the amount to move to the bottom.